# Give an example to show that the same conclusion does not follow if we allow some weights to be nonpositive

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following question please.

**Q**: Argue that if all edge weights of a graph are positive, then any subset of edges that
connects all vertices and has minimum total weight must be a tree. Give an example
to show that the same conclusion does not follow if we allow some weights to be
nonpositive.

**Attempt**: to answer the counterexample part not the first, if we have a complete graph $K_3$ that is a triangle with all negative weights,
[image]

If we run Minimum spanning tree algorithms like prime and kruskals, we would get

[image]

Which is a MST.

However, the solution I got says the following:

> To see that this conclusion is not true if we allow negative edge
> weights, we provide a construction. Consider the graph $K_3$ 3 with
> all edge weights equal to −1. The only minimum weight set of edges
> that connects the graph has total weight −3, and consists of all the
> edges. This is clearly not a MST because it is not a tree, which can
> be easily seen because it has one more edge than a tree on three
> vertices should have. Any MST of this weighted graph must have weight
> that is at least −2.

**Problem**: why the minimum weight set of edges that connect a graph in this case is -3, which means it's not MST as it has a cycle please? Could we have the figure with 2 edges and weight -2 drawn above please?

Comment: Because $-3$ is less than $-2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question didn't ask for a minimum spanning tree.  It asked for a minimal subset of edges that included every vertex.  This explicitly turns out NOT to be a tree if you allow negative weights.

Running an algorithm designed to make a tree is of course not going to give you a non tree!

Your tree is an example of a set of edges that connect all the vertices,  with total weight -2.  This is clearly not minimal as the whole graph has total weight -3.